# How to get data from API and print it in a list then post to a different API? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, heroku, dio

in one of the signup process pages I am writing, I am trying to print what's in **category/total** api (which prints all of **id** and **category**) into a list, and then post however many is selected by a new user to a different api (which contains **user_id** and **category_id**) eventually. Previously, I have written an array with values that I wrote manually:

```
class CustomListView_frequentlyUsed extends StatefulWidget {
  final int currentUserId;
  final int categoryId;
  final String display_name;

  CustomListView_frequentlyUsed(
      {Key? key,
      required this.currentUserId,
      required this.categoryId,
      required this.display_name})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomListView_frequentlyUsed> createState() =>
      _CustomListView_frequentlyUsedState();
}

class _CustomListView_frequentlyUsedState
    extends State<CustomListView_frequentlyUsed> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          Text(
            widget.display_name,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Text(
            "Please select your interest",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Wrap(
              children: [
                "Game",
                "Netflix(Movie TV)",
                "Current Event",
                "Sports & Fitness",
                "Politics",
                "Career & Business",
                "Art & Music",
                "Tech",
                "Food",
              ].map((f) => CommonItems(f)).toList(),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            "Choose at lease one category",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/student');
            },
            child: Text("Next"),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CommonItems extends StatefulWidget {
  final String f;

  CommonItems(this.f);

  @override
  _CommonItemsState createState() => _CommonItemsState();
}

class _CommonItemsState extends State<CommonItems> {
  bool isClicked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 5.0, right: 5.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isClicked ? Colors.orange : Colors.transparent,
          border: Border.all(
            color: isClicked ? Colors.orange : Color(0xFF282f61),
            width: 2.0,
          ),
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0) //
              ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          widget.f,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 16.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          isClicked = !isClicked;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to change that array to whatever is in **category/total** and then post the formData to the **relation** api (**user_id** and **category_id**) then go to the next page when I click the elevated button.

I am using the **dio** package for **get** and **post**. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 Future fetchCategories() async {

    Response response;
    try {
      response = await dio.request(
        Url + '/category/total', //URL is declared already
        options: Options(method: 'get', headers: {'x-access-tokens': token}),
      );
      return response.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response!.statusCode == 400) {
        print(e.response);
        return e.response!.data;
      } else {
        print(e.message);
      }

    }
  }

  Future postCategories(userId, categoryId) async {
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'user_id': userId,
      'category_id': categoryId 
    }); 
      try {
      dio.options.contentType = Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType;
      final response = await dio.post<Map<String, dynamic>>(
          URL + '/relation/category_relation', //URL is declared already
          options: Options(
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'accept': "application/json", 'x-access-tokens': token},
          ),
          data: formData);
      print(response.toString());
      return response.data;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      if (e.response!.statusCode == 500) {
        print(e.response);
        return e.response!.data;
      } else {
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
  }
```

I would love your help to achieve what I want to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand your problem. If you can tell me about the scenario or exactly what you want to do, I can write the code and send it to you.